# Collecting on different Frequent Flyer programmes on same booking (not same flights)

Tags: loyalty-programs, klm, delta-air-lines, flying-blue, virgin-atlantic

I booked Delta but 2 of 3 flights are operated by Virgin Atlantic, so I cannot get miles on Flying Blue (Air France-KLM's programme) as the flight isn't operated by a SkyTeam airline.

Can I collect on my Delta flight, and claim the other two flights on Virgin's Flying Club? Anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 8):

You can change the frequent flyer number for earning prior to each flight. Make sure you get a new printed boarding pass so that you can send it in if there is a problem crediting the flight.

Alternatively, if you don't have status in any of the airline programmes and are not using your frequent flyer number to gain benefits such as lounge access, you can just put no frequent flyer number at all and apply for retro-credit after flying. This presumes you're already a member of both programmes.

You may be able to change your frequent flyer number at a ticketing kiosk, in the lounge, at the gate, or at an airline ticketing desk and in some cases you can do this online, but this may not be reliable very close to departure.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware, you can't spread one booking across multiple loyalty programmes. I recently flew from the UK to the US and back flying out on a code-share operated by Virgin and back on Delta. This was a single ticket booked with Delta and the booking page, as I recall, only had one space for one loyalty programme. Both legs of the journey were credited to my Delta mileage account.

Comment: not even if I remove the Frequent Flyer number from the booking and claim the Delta flight with FlyingBlue and the Virgin Flights with Virgin afterwards? Will this work? there's no point of me joining Delta skyMiles

Comment: @Thorbjorn Yes that will work.